Better control cascading triggers in SQLite
I'm working with two interdependent SpatiaLite layers.
When I delete entities from the first layer (ESPECES_PT), I also delete corresponding entries from the second layer (ESPECES_ATTRIBUTS). However, when only a few entities are deleted, and similar ones still exist in the same table (ESPECES_PT), I need to update specific fields (nbr_ent and eff_tot).
The problem arises when I delete large portions of the table. Sometimes, hundreds of identical entities exist in ESPECES_PT, so each deletion triggers updates to my fields until the last deletion, which simply removes the row.
To complicate things further, the update of these two fields also triggers two additional triggers. While everything works smoothly when deleting a few entities as part of the workflow, deleting the entire table causes massive updates across the layers right before everything is deleted. This process is inefficient and can be very slow.
I don't think I can disable the field updates for batch deletions, as the deletions are performed row by row, and SQLite cannot anticipate that the entire table is being deleted.
This is the trigger for deletion :
CREATE TRIGGER F_delete_esp 
AFTER DELETE ON ESPECES_PT 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
    

    DELETE FROM ESPECES_ATTRIBUTS 
    WHERE nom_simple = OLD.nom_simple
    AND nom_simple <> 'Absent'
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ESPECES_PT WHERE nom_simple = OLD.nom_simple)
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SAISIE_LISTES WHERE SAISIE_LISTES.ID = ESPECES_ATTRIBUTS.ID_REL AND ID_REL > 0); 
 
    UPDATE ESPECES_ATTRIBUTS
        SET nbr_ent = nbr_ent - 1,
            eff_tot = eff_tot - OLD.effectif_p   
    WHERE id_sp = OLD.id_sp;
     
END;

Which will triggers:
CREATE TRIGGER B_updt_nbrent
AFTER UPDATE OF nbr_ent ON ESPECES_ATTRIBUTS
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    UPDATE ESPECES_ATTRIBUTS
    SET geom_exists = (
            CASE 
                WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ESPECES_PT b WHERE b.id_sp = NEW.id_sp AND b.geom IS NOT NULL) THEN 'Localisé(e)' 
                ELSE 'Non localisé(e)'  
            END)
    WHERE nom_simple = (SELECT nom_simple FROM ESPECES_ATTRIBUTS WHERE id = NEW.id);

    UPDATE ESPECES_HABITATS_ATTRIBUTS
    SET nbr_ent = NEW.nbr_ent 
    WHERE NEW.nbr_ent <> nbr_ent
        AND nom_simple = (SELECT nom_simple FROM ESPECES_ATTRIBUTS WHERE id = NEW.id);
END;

And
CREATE TRIGGER updt_efftot
AFTER UPDATE OF eff_tot ON ESPECES_ATTRIBUTS 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
    UPDATE ESPECES_ATTRIBUTS
    SET concat_lib = Coalesce((
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(habitat_info, ', ')
        FROM (
            SELECT 
                Coalesce(NULLIF(CASE WHEN HABITATS_POLY.EUNIS_1 IS NOT NULL AND SUBSTR(HABITATS_POLY.EUNIS_1,1,1) <> '[' THEN '[' || SUBSTR(HABITATS_POLY.EUNIS_1,1,1) ELSE '' END ||
                CASE WHEN HABITATS_POLY.EUNIS_2 IS NOT NULL AND SUBSTR(HABITATS_POLY.EUNIS_2,1,1) <> '[' THEN ', '|| SUBSTR(HABITATS_POLY.EUNIS_2,1,1) ELSE '' END ||
                CASE WHEN HABITATS_POLY.EUNIS_3 IS NOT NULL AND SUBSTR(HABITATS_POLY.EUNIS_3,1,1) <> '[' THEN ', '|| SUBSTR(HABITATS_POLY.EUNIS_3,1,1) ELSE '' END ||
                CASE WHEN HABITATS_POLY.EUNIS_4 IS NOT NULL AND SUBSTR(HABITATS_POLY.EUNIS_4,1,1) <> '[' THEN ', '|| SUBSTR(HABITATS_POLY.EUNIS_4,1,1) ELSE '' END ||
                '] ','] '), '') ||  
                HABITATS_POLY.lib_physio || ' (' ||
                (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(EP.effectif_p), 0) 
                 FROM ESPECES_PT EP
                 WHERE EP.nom_simple = NEW.nom_simple
                   AND HABITATS_POLY.lib_physio IS NOT NULL AND EP.st_lb_phy = HABITATS_POLY.lib_physio
                ) || ')' AS habitat_info
            FROM HABITATS_POLY
            WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ESPECES_PT EP WHERE EP.nom_simple = NEW.nom_simple AND EP.geom IS NOT NULL AND ST_Intersects(HABITATS_POLY.geom, EP.geom))
            GROUP BY HABITATS_POLY.lib_physio
        ) AS habitat_subquery)
        ,'-')
    WHERE id = NEW.id;
END;

Which will triggers:
CREATE TRIGGER updt_hab 
AFTER UPDATE OF add_poly, delim, habitat, distance, tampon, nbr_ent, limite_hab, concat_lib ON ESPECES_HABITATS_ATTRIBUTS 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 

    UPDATE TABLE_VARIABLES
    SET updt_hab = 1
    WHERE id = 1;

    DELETE FROM TABLE_ESP_HABS
    WHERE nom_simple = NEW.nom_simple
        AND vdelim <> NEW.delim;

    UPDATE TABLE_ESP_HABS
    SET vdelim = NEW.delim,
        add_value = NEW.add_poly
    WHERE nom_simple = NEW.nom_simple;

    DELETE FROM LISTE_ESPECES_PO
    WHERE spec = NEW.nom_simple
    AND dval <> 'Liaison EHA'
    AND (--(NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ESPECES_HABITATS_ATTRIBUTS WHERE spec = NEW.nom_simple))
        (NEW.add_poly = 'Non'
        OR (NEW.delim IS NOT NULL AND (dval <> NEW.delim OR dval = NEW.delim AND (NEW.tampon IS NOT NULL AND NEW.tampon <> tampon))
        OR (NEW.habitat IS NOT NULL AND habit <> Replace(NEW.habitat,'"',''))
        OR (NEW.cd_hab IS NOT NULL AND cdhab <> Replace(NEW.cd_hab,'"',''))
        OR dist <> NEW.distance
        OR (NEW.limite_hab IS NOT NULL AND limhab <> NEW.limite_hab)
        OR (NEW.concat_lib IS NOT NULL AND conclib <> NEW.concat_lib)
        OR nbent <> NEW.nbr_ent)));
    
    UPDATE ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY 
    SET espece = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(ESPECE, NEW.nom_simple || ',', ''), ',' || NEW.nom_simple, ''), NEW.nom_simple, ''), 
        espece_m = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(espece_m, NEW.nom_simple || ',', ''), ',' || NEW.nom_simple, ''), NEW.nom_simple, ''),
        nom_vernac = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(nom_vernac, NEW.nom_simple || ',', ''), ',' || NEW.nom_simple, ''), NEW.nom_simple, ''), 
        pres_poly = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(pres_poly, NEW.nom_simple || ',', ''), ',' || NEW.nom_simple, ''), NEW.nom_simple, ''), 
        prox_poly = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(prox_poly, NEW.nom_simple || ',', ''), ',' || NEW.nom_simple, ''), NEW.nom_simple, '')
    WHERE INSTR(ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY.ESPECE, NEW.nom_simple) > 0 
        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM LISTE_ESPECES_PO WHERE spec = NEW.nom_simple AND id_poly <> 'Liaison EHA');
        
    INSERT INTO ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY (espece, nom_vernac, id_rel, geom, COMPART, Dval, LIB_PHYSIO, pres_poly, prox_poly, last_sp)      --visibilite, vfilter, 
    SELECT
        --'Oui' AS visibilite,
        --1 AS vfilter,
        '{' || NEW.nom_simple || '}' AS espece,
        '{' || NEW.nom_simple || '}' AS nom_vernac,
        CASE 
            WHEN NEW.delim = 'Habitat' THEN EP_HP.pk
            ELSE 'T' || NEW.pk
        END AS id_rel,
        CASE
            WHEN NEW.delim = 'Habitat' THEN EP_HP.hp_geom
            ELSE ST_Multi(ST_Union(
                CASE 
                    WHEN NEW.limite_hab = 'Contrainte' THEN ST_Intersection(ST_Buffer(EP_HP.ep_geom, NEW.tampon), EP_HP.hp_geom)
                    ELSE ST_Buffer(EP_HP.ep_geom, NEW.tampon)
                END
            ))
        END AS geom,
        NEW.compart,
        NEW.delim,
        CASE WHEN NEW.delim = 'Habitat' THEN EP_HP.rel_ehp ELSE NULL END AS LIB_PHYSIO,
        CASE 
            WHEN NEW.delim = 'Tampon' OR (NEW.geo_ex = 'Localisé(e)' AND EXISTS (
                SELECT 1 FROM ESPECES_PT EPT 
                WHERE ST_Contains(EP_HP.hp_geom, EPT.geom) AND EPT.nom_simple = NEW.nom_simple
            )) THEN '{' || NEW.nom_simple || '}' 
            ELSE NULL 
        END AS pres_poly,
        CASE 
            WHEN NEW.delim = 'Habitat' AND ((NEW.geo_ex = 'Localisé(e)' AND NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT 1 FROM ESPECES_PT EPT 
                WHERE ST_Contains(EP_HP.hp_geom, EPT.geom) AND EPT.nom_simple = NEW.nom_simple
            )) OR NEW.geo_ex = 'Non localisé(e)') THEN '{' || NEW.nom_simple || '}' 
            ELSE NULL 
        END AS prox_poly,
        NEW.nom_simple AS last_sp
    FROM (
        SELECT EP.geom AS ep_geom, HP.geom AS hp_geom, HP.pk, HP.rel_ehp
        FROM ESPECES_PT EP
        LEFT JOIN HABITATS_POLY HP ON 
            CASE 
                WHEN NEW.delim = 'Habitat' THEN ST_Distance(HP.geom, EP.geom) <= NEW.distance
                ELSE ST_Intersects(ST_Buffer(EP.geom, NEW.tampon), HP.geom)
            END
        WHERE EP.nom_simple = NEW.nom_simple
    ) AS EP_HP
    WHERE NEW.add_poly = 'Oui'
        AND (
            (NEW.delim = 'Habitat' AND instr(NEW.habitat, EP_HP.rel_ehp) > 0)
            OR (NEW.delim = 'Tampon' AND NEW.geo_ex = 'Localisé(e)' AND NEW.limite_hab IS NOT NULL AND NEW.tampon > 0)
        )
        AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 FROM ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY EHP 
            WHERE (NEW.delim = 'Habitat' AND NEW.compart = EHP.COMPART AND EHP.id_rel = EP_HP.pk)
                OR (NEW.delim = 'Tampon' AND EHP.id_rel = 'T' || NEW.pk)
        )
        AND (
            NEW.geo_ex = 'Non localisé(e)'
            OR NEW.delim = 'Tampon'
            OR EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ESPECES_PT EPT WHERE ST_Distance(EP_HP.hp_geom, EPT.geom) <= NEW.distance AND EPT.nom_simple = NEW.nom_simple)
        )
    GROUP BY 
        CASE WHEN NEW.delim = 'Habitat' THEN EP_HP.pk ELSE NEW.pk END;
    
    UPDATE ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY
    SET espece = 
            CASE 
                WHEN ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY.espece IS NULL OR ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY.espece = '{}' THEN '{' || NEW.nom_simple || '}'
                ELSE substr(ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY.espece, 1, length(ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY.espece) - 1) || ',' || NEW.nom_simple || '}'
            END, 
        nom_vernac = 
            CASE 
                WHEN ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY.nom_vernac IS NULL OR ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY.nom_vernac = '{}' THEN '{' || NEW.nom_simple || '}'
                ELSE substr(ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY.nom_vernac, 1, length(ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY.nom_vernac) - 1) || ',' || NEW.nom_simple || '}'
            END,
        pres_poly = 
            CASE 
            WHEN (NEW.geo_ex = 'Localisé(e)' AND ST_Contains(HP.geom, EP.geom)) THEN 
                CASE 
                    WHEN pres_poly IS NULL OR pres_poly = '{}' THEN '{' || NEW.nom_simple || '}' 
                    ELSE COALESCE(NULLIF(substr(ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY.pres_poly, 1, length(ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY.pres_poly) - 1), ''), '') || ',' || NEW.nom_simple || '}' 
                END 
            ELSE ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY.pres_poly 
        END, 
        prox_poly = 
            CASE 
            WHEN (NEW.geo_ex = 'Localisé(e)' AND NOT ST_Contains(HP.geom, EP.geom)) OR NEW.geo_ex = 'Non localisé(e)' THEN 
                CASE 
                    WHEN prox_poly IS NULL OR prox_poly = '{}' THEN '{' || NEW.nom_simple || '}' 
                    ELSE COALESCE(NULLIF(substr(ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY.prox_poly, 1, length(ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY.prox_poly) - 1), ''), '') || ',' || NEW.nom_simple || '}' 
                END 
            ELSE ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY.prox_poly 
        END,
        last_sp = NEW.nom_simple
    FROM HABITATS_POLY HP 
        LEFT JOIN ESPECES_PT EP ON ST_Distance(HP.geom, EP.geom) <= NEW.distance 
    WHERE NEW.add_poly = 'Oui' 
        AND NEW.delim = 'Habitat' 
        AND INSTR(NEW.habitat, HP.lib_physio) > 0 
        AND ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY.compart = NEW.COMPART 
        AND ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY.ESPECE NOT LIKE '%' || NEW.nom_simple || '%' 
        AND ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY.id_rel = HP.pk 
        AND ((NEW.geo_ex = 'Localisé(e)' AND EP.nom_simple = NEW.nom_simple) OR (NEW.geo_ex = 'Non localisé(e)')); 

    INSERT INTO TABLE_ADD_ESPECES (bal, espece_m, id_rel) 
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        1,
        NEW.nom_simple, 
        source.source_id
    FROM (SELECT NEW.nom_simple) AS new_species
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT source_id 
        FROM TABLE_HISTO_GEOM 
        WHERE spname = NEW.nom_simple
    ) AS source
    WHERE NEW.nom_simple IS NOT NULL AND NEW.nom_simple <> ''
        AND NEW.cd_hab LIKE '%' || 'Ajout manuel' || '%'
        AND NEW.add_poly = 'Oui'
        AND NEW.delim = 'Habitat';

    DELETE FROM LISTE_ESPECES_HAB 
    WHERE nom_esp = NEW.nom_simple
    AND (NEW.add_poly = 'Non'
        OR (NEW.delim IS NOT NULL AND (OLD.delim <> NEW.delim OR OLD.delim = NEW.delim AND (NEW.tampon IS NOT NULL AND NEW.tampon <> OLD.tampon))
        OR (NEW.habitat IS NOT NULL AND NEW.habitat <> OLD.habitat)
        OR (NEW.cd_hab IS NOT NULL AND NEW.cd_hab <> OLD.cd_hab)
        OR OLD.distance <> NEW.distance));
                
    INSERT INTO LISTE_ESPECES_HAB (nom_esp, asso_cd, asso_habit, compart) 
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        EHA.nom_simple,
        EHA.cd_hab,     
        EHA.habitat,
        EHA.compart 
    FROM ESPECES_HABITATS_ATTRIBUTS EHA 
    WHERE EHA.PK = NEW.PK 
        AND EHA.nom_simple IS NOT NULL 
        AND EHA.add_poly = 'Oui' 
        AND (EHA.habitat IS NOT NULL OR EHA.cd_hab LIKE '%' || 'Ajout manuel' || '%')
        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM LISTE_ESPECES_HAB WHERE nom_esp = EHA.nom_simple); 

    UPDATE LISTE_ESPECES_HAB 
    SET asso_habit = NEW.habitat 
    WHERE nom_esp = NEW.nom_simple 
        AND asso_habit <> NEW.habitat;
    
    UPDATE TABLE_VARIABLES
    SET updt_hab = 0
    WHERE id = 1;
    
END;

Which will triggers... other ones...
My main issue is that I need these triggers to function when I delete a single feature, but given how my project is set up, I don't think there's an easy solution.

I'm thinking of a solution using flags and timestamp.

During deletion : add a first flag (flag = 1) in ESPECES_ATTRIBUTS where nom_simple = OLD.nom_simple (so I can identify which values have been modified)
Still during deletion, saving a flag in a temporary table (UPDATE TABLE_VARIABLES SET updt_interv = 1, tim_eupdt = DATE('now', 'localtime') WHERE id = 1
For every update/insert/delete in ESPECES_PT : If updt_interv  = 1 and the difference between tim_eupdt  and DATE('now', 'localtime') > 1 mins (or 5) ; then update all the values in ESPECES_ATTRIBUTS WHERE flag = 1.


How about better sanitizing inserts into ESPECES_ATTRIBUTS, i.e. not having duplicates to begin with? Also, are you saying a) you are repeatedly truncating the main table, and b) when that is the case, all downstream/related tables are supposed to end up empty, too?

There are no duplicates in ESPECES_ATTRIBUTS; this table contains the attributes of the entities from the main layer : ESPECES_PT.  Duplicates exist on the main layer.
When I empty the main table (ESPECES_PT), ESPECES_ATTRIBUTS must also be emptied. However, when I delete only a few features from ESPECES_PT, ESPECES_ATTRIBUTS must be updated. These updates are triggering multiple other triggers.
I'm not repeatedly truncating the main table, but due to how SQLite works, each deleted row is processed individually, which can lead to unnecessary updates.

Regarding other (downstream) layers (ESPECES_HABITATS_ATTRIBUTS ; HABITATS_POLY, etc.) it depends, but it does not cause any issue.

If you're deleting all rows, use TRUNCATE TABLE.

Some ideas, beside the simple truncate 1) Use a view to compute the "quantities" instead of triggers. 2) use a DB that supports statement level triggers, such as Postgres, 3) Have a single trigger that stores the processed ID (anything: insert, delete, update). In QGIS, listen to layer save events and call a new function in your DB that consumes distinct values from the table of processed IDs and applies the logic from your current triggers.

@Vince @JGH SQLite does not have an explicit TRUNCATE command, just an optimizer on DELETE. That'd be too easy. Also, the docs mention that "SQLite can only use the TRUNCATE optimizer if the table (to truncate) does not have any triggers."

(Actually, to be pedantic, that's cited from elsewhere; the docs read: "When the WHERE clause and RETURNING clause are both omitted from a DELETE statement and the table being deleted has no triggers, SQLite uses an optimization to erase the entire table content without having to visit each row of the table individually." - emphasis mine)

Heh. I guess SQLite is too light for usefulness in this context. Not having a TRUNCATE is akin to stating, "We support the full alphabet, except for J and Q".

Could you somehow put all deletes into one transaction? In SQLite it is slow to initialize a transaction doing anything massive row by row is really suboptimal.

I cannot use transactions inside a trigger in sqlite.
I chose sqlite because it doesn't require to install any other software than QGIS. It is practical, especially for my colleagues, to use the same project in several computers.
But in a long term I might put the project on a server where postgre is installed and everyone will access it from the server.

Most of the updates are necessary, as all tables are interconnected. When I delete an entry in one table, it is crucial to update the counts of entities, spatial intersections, individuals, and other relevant data to ensure that all information remains accurate. I will make a plan of all the triggers to better understand what is executed and see if I can do something better. Or eventually, delete some operation (like sum of individuals).

If deleting a large number of rows is slow, have you considered to copy everything that you want to keep into new tables, perhaps in a new attached database?


Do not allow duplicates on the main table ESPECES_PT in the first place; just add a BEFORE INSERT trigger.
Not sure, but it sounds like with better sanitizing there is a chance that you may be able to greatly simplify your ON DELETE trigger chain, or that you are not even in need for them at all.

If you absolutely want or need to keep that trigger chain as close as possible to what it is now, implement conditional trigger execution via separate settings table; a bare minimum example:
CREATE TABLE table_settings (
   settings_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
   schema_name TEXT,
   table_name TEXT,
   flagged_for_truncate BOOL DEFAULT FALSE
);

INSERT INTO table_settings (schema_name, table_name)
  VALUES ('<SCHEMA>', 'ESPECES_PT')
;

-- SPARSE DELETE/UPDATE trigger
-- this is your initial trigger as in your question
CREATE TRIGGER F_delete_esp 
  AFTER DELETE ON ESPECES_PT
  -- check if we want to DELETE/UPDATE
  WHEN (SELECT flagged_for_truncate FROM table_settings WHERE schema_name = '<SCHEMA>' AND table_name = 'ESPECES_PT') = FALSE
  FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN 
     <UPDATE ALL CHILD RELATIONS AND FOLLOW TRIGGER CHAIN>
    END
;

-- [optional] TRUNCATE trigger
CREATE TRIGGER F_truncate_esp 
  AFTER DELETE ON ESPECES_PT
  -- check if we want a TRUNCATE
  WHEN (SELECT flagged_for_truncate FROM table_settings WHERE schema_name = '<SCHEMA>' AND table_name = 'ESPECES_PT') = TRUE
  FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN 
     <DELETE FROM ALL CHILD RELATIONS SKIPPING TRIGGER CHAIN>
    END
;

All you'd have to do is to UPDATE table_settings SET flagged_for_truncate = TRUE WHERE ...; whenever you want to TRUNCATE, and revert after!
You can add all sorts of fine-tuning to that table, have settings per trigger or whatever; the TRUNCATE trigger is optional as you may just as well add flags for all child tables and conditionals to their triggers, and run a DELETE on them directly. Make sure that this doesn't accidentally fire off any ON DELETE triggers on child relations - you'd want to add an own entry to the table_settings table to handle that correctly. Better yet, if the downstream trigger logic is only ever needed for this DELETE operation, put all logic inside the main trigger on the main table!
Note:
You may find it very useful to execute a TRUNCATE inside an explicit (write) transaction, as that means no-one else can execute a SPARSE DELETE/UPDATE while you are in TRUNCATE mode (or any other write operations, that is):
BEGIN IMMEDIATE TRANSACTION;

UPDATE
  table_settings
SET
  flagged_for_truncate = TRUE
WHERE
  schema_name = '<SCHEMA>'
  AND
  table_name = '<TABLE>'
;

DELETE FROM <TABLE>;

UPDATE
  table_settings
SET
  flagged_for_truncate = FALSE
WHERE
  schema_name = '<SCHEMA>'
  AND
  table_name = '<TABLE>'
;

END TRANSACTION;




Don't pin me down on syntax here - as @Vince has put it rather splendidly, SQLite may - why, or may not - use an alphabet without J and Q, and sometimes with A though F being hexadecimal numbers instead of letters., especially on Tuesdays....

The main layer must contain duplicates since it holds all the data from the project. My issue is that SQLite cannot differentiate between occasional deletions and a complete deletion of the table’s content. The project is used by colleagues who are unfamiliar with how SQLite works (and I'm not entirely sure myself). This means they won’t be running SQLite queries.
I revised the project’s execution plan and optimized a trigger that was excessively slow. With some additional optimizations, the deletion process is now significantly faster.

I might also add a tickable field in an 'OPTIONS' layer, allowing the entire project content to be deleted without triggering all the associated code.
